# In C#, can a method return List such that clients can only read it, but not write to it?

Tags: c#, constants, encapsulation, immutability, readonly

Let's say I have a C# class:

```
class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> _barList;
    List<Bar> GetBarList() { return _barList; }
...
}
```

A client can call it:

```
var barList = foo.GetBarList();
barList.Add( ... );
```

Is there a way to make the `Add` method fail because only a read-only version of `_barList` is returned?

Comment: Remember that even though you can't add or remove objects from the list you can still modify the objects in the list (set values on properties, call methods that change state).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, in `GetBarList()`  return `_barList.AsReadOnly()`.

**Edit:**
As Michael pointed out below, your method would have to return an `IList<Bar>`.

Comment: Nice! Note that, since this returns a ReadOnlyCollection, which implements IList, your accessor must also return an IList, and not a List.

Answer (score 4):

You may try to use [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). Or return just IEnumerable from your method, clients will not have methods to modify it.

Comment: The former is better as the latter can be cast back to a List